# fs.writeFile() doesn't work on Meteor 0.6.5.1

Tags: meteor

I was using Meteor 0.6.4.1 and used `Npm.require('fs')` and `fs.writeFile()`to save files. Here is the code I used to test it: [Gist for save files](https://gist.github.com/camilosw/6436821). I updated Meteor to 0.6.5.1 and got this error:

```
(STDERR) app/server/save_file.js:18
(STDERR)         throw (new Meteor.Error(500, 'Failed to save file. ' + err));
(STDERR)                ^
(STDERR) Error: Failed to save file. Error: ENOENT, open 'public/carlos.png' [500]
(STDERR)     at Meteor.methods.saveFile (app/server/save_file.js:18:16)
(STDERR)     at fs.writeFile (fs.js:746:21)
(STDERR)     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
```

I know that node version changed from 0.8.18 to 0.8.24 on Meteor 0.6.5. It's a bug on the 0.8.24 node version or the Meteor 0.6.5 version? It's there any way to solve it or I must stay with 0.6.4.1 Meteor version?

Comment: Modify your code a bit to get a bit more detail. Specifically the line `throw (new Meteor.Error(500, 'Failed to save file.', err));` to `throw (new Meteor.Error(500, 'Failed to save file" + err));` to see a bit more detail on what the callback returns as the error. That or look for the stack trace thats supposed to be visible (perhaps a bit further down that you didn't include?)

Comment: I edited the code, but only the four line changed with a little more info about the error. I copied all the lines, there are no more after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Meteor 0.6.5, they changed the current working directory in the server context, it used to be the Meteor root directory but it is now `MyProject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server`.

So if you want to access something in the public folder from the server side app, you could try this path : `../../../../../public/`.

Warning : writing files to `public` might cause the server to restart and lead to undefined behaviour.